# How to change function description in derived class with Doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have two classes:

```
class A {
public:
  /** Brief description
   * Grand description
   */
  virtual void func() {
    // Do something.
  }
};

class B: public A {
  // How to re-describe func() here?
};
```

I have turned on description inheritance in Doxygen config, and that is fine. But I want to change description in derived class to some functions, implemented in base class, *without* reimplementing these functions.

Of course, I can do the following:

```
class B: public A {
public:
  /** My new description.
   * ...
   */
  virtual void func() {
    A::func();
  }
};
```

But it seems "ugly" to me - to write unnecessery code just to add some comments.

Are there other solutions?

Comment: If you haven't overridden the function in the derived class... why would the documentation for the function change?

Comment: The interface of the functions, and more importantly the behavior of the function hasn't changed, so personally I see no reason to create new and possibly duplicated documentation.

Comment: And what do you want to achieve by doing that?

Comment: @NicolBolas: In my case, the function is a getter of some private value (logical size), that slightly changes it's meaning and range of possible values in different derived classes. I don't pretend that my class architecture is the good one. I just want to know if there are some ways to use Doxygen-style comments without additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to you can also use a preprocessor trick:

```
class B: public A {
  public:

#ifdef ONLY_FOR_DOXYGEN
    /** Beautiful docs */
    virtual void func();
#endif
};
```

along with these settings:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = ONLY_FOR_DOXYGEN
```

That way only doxygen sees the extra code.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you want to hear, but it seems that doxygen can't invent documentation for entities that aren't in the code, and the idea that the same function should have the same documentation seems sensible.

The best I can think of is to put a section in your `A` documentation to the effect of:

```
/** Brief
 * \par For Class A
 *  Class A details...
 * \par For Class B
 *  Class B details...
 */
```

This should put the same documentation for both and the reader can pick out the relevant section?

This means they'll still have to have the same brief description, though.